# Where To Add Children?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

Let's say that my domain consists of the obligatory Parent -> Child relationship. When given a `Parent`, where is the recommended place I sould add a new `Child` in regards to Controllers?

Would I use `ParentController.AddChild()` or `ChildController.Add()`? Any reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, what is your aggregate root?, most of the cases it will be ParentController.AddChild() as the parent is the aggregate root like Order.AddLineItem(), and some other times the opposite like Order.SetCustomer().

Comment: If Parent is my aggregate root. In that case I assume `ChildController.Add(int parentId)` would be wrong? I should always use `ParentController.AddChild()`.

Comment: Yes that is true, as the Parent is the controller and information expert (aggregate root) it should be the responsible for the construction.